Socket IO not working after deployment in MERN stack, it works fine locally but refuses to connect on deployment
The error i am getting
GET https://gamifyv2.vercel.app/socket.io/?userId=6655d30f6a78f46c8a9d43cd&EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O_Du2lF 404 (Not Found)
create @ index-BtS0T3eS.js:419
ve @ index-BtS0T3eS.js:25
index-BtS0T3eS.js:419 Connection error:  Error: xhr poll error
    at zne.onError (index-BtS0T3eS.js:419:124808)
    at Dr.<anonymous> (index-BtS0T3eS.js:419:128160)
    at vt.emit (index-BtS0T3eS.js:419:123341)
    at Dr.onError (index-BtS0T3eS.js:419:129567)
    at index-BtS0T3eS.js:419:129340```

my socket server
const io = new Server(server, {
cors: {
origin: \["http://localhost:3000", "https://gamifyv2.vercel.app"\],
methods: \["GET", "POST"\],
credentials: true,
},
});

frontend vite config
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "https://gamifybeta-1.onrender.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: true, // Change to true for HTTPS
      },
      "/socket.io": {
        target: "https://gamifybeta-1.onrender.com",
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: true, // Change to true for HTTPS
        cookieDomainRewrite: "localhost",
      },
    },
  },
});

connection frontend
const socket = io("https://gamifybeta-1.onrender.com/socket.io", {
      query: {
        userId: user?._id,
      },
    });

deployed site - Gamify
I have tried to change the connection urls using trial and errors a bit and was having issues in the connection of normal functionalities so it took me time on that, cookies were not setting properly on deployment, but thats working now
So only this socket is refusing to connect now
I think i am making a small mistake somewhere but i have searched and tried a lot but don't seem to find a solution

